# Input onChange handler handler don't work - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

My Input's handler works fine for the first 2 changes, on the 3rd change it throws an error:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  ...

  const handleFieldChange = useCallback((field, e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setFields(prevstate => ({
      ...prevstate,
      [field]: e.target.value
    }))
  }, [setFields]);

  ...


  <TextField
     className={cx('input')}
     label="Email"
     value={fields.email}
     variant="outlined"
     onChange={(e) => handleFieldChange('email',e)}
  />
```

So far I tried to remove the `useCallback` and it behaves the same way.

Comment: `<TextField/>` is from some sort of UI framework you need to check their docs wheather they are sending the value of dom ! I think it will work fine in `<input/>`

Comment: Yap, it's from Material UI, I'll check

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd I tried with regular input and it still is not working :/

Answer (score 0):

yeah! I found dependency must be the value it is function here `

```
const handleFieldChange = useCallback((field, e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setFields(prevstate => ({
      ...prevstate,
      [field]: e.target.value
    }))
  }, [fields.email]);`
```

by the way `useCallback` can be used for expensive calculations i think it's not required here

```
const handleFieldChange = (field,e)=>{
 // your logic
}
```

this is good enough!

check out this docs for more https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback/

Comment: `const handleFieldChange = (field, e) => 
    setFields(prevstate => ({
      ...prevstate,
      [field]: e.target.value
    }))` this shoud work for sure

Comment: btw I get a solution, but I don't know how good it is. I just removed the callback in `setFields` and changed it to this : `setFields({...fields, [field]: e.target.value})`

Comment: this will be good in your case no need of `useCallback`

Comment: can u move that to sandbox and send the link ? this is weird it should work

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `useCallback`. It will memoise the function, and give the same function every time, as long as the dependencies are the same, which is not what you want here.

It adds a lot of overhead, which actually will make the performance slower in your case.

[Read more](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) about why you shouldn't use it, by one of the guys who made it.

Just remove the `useCallback` bit and it will work:

```
  const handleFieldChange = (field, e) => 
    setFields(prevstate => ({
      ...prevstate,
      [field]: e.target.value
    }))
```

---

A further recommendation would be to not do the weird string handling stuff to edit state, with the new hooks we can have multiple different state, and it is more effieicnet to split them up separately, and much more readable code too.

```
const MainComponent = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Password"
        value={password}
        onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

Another Alternative so that state is in one object - notice how I have avoided trying to access the state object by passing a string key through, but kept it clean and in one place:

```
const MainComponent = () => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        label="Email"
        value={fields.email}
        onChange={e => setFields({ ...fields, email: e.target.value })}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Password"
        value={fields.password}
        onChange={e => setFields({ ...fields, password: e.target.value })}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

See sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-wood-fsru6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Nope, sorry it didn't work too, and I need to keep my info of fields in a single object. I just tried to change the state without callback and it worked

Comment: What didn't work? Why do they need to be in a single object? It's cleaner to keep them separate for the easier inputting, and then when you send them off somewhere else, join them together at that point. And something did work?

Comment: Yes, your right I can use it with the separate way that you suggested, but it means that I can't change objects with hooks through inputs? I think there is some way to do this

Comment: Yes there is a way to do anything, like I (and another answer) stated already, your original code would have mostly worked if you just removed `useCallback`

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan I've added another code snippet, and also a CodeSandbox link showing it working.